# Count conditionally formatted value that is not hidden

Tags: excel, vba

Every cell that has a value of 0, that row will be hidden. And any value that is outside the minimum and maximum values ​​will be red.

How to identify red color but active (not hidden)?

I used `range.displayformat.interior.color = vbred`

The cells are red but hidden are also counted.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro when you do it manually? It will give you a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, the visible cells will be formatted

```
Set rng = Range("Your range").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng = ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed
```

Comment: how is the code if add "if"?

Comment: what kind of "if" do you want to apply? give me your sample code. I could help

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code for the "if" condition that you ask for.

```
Sub Highlight_Greater_Than()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Rng As Range
Dim ColorCell As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Name")
Set rng = Range("Your range").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    'rng = ActiveCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = vbRed
Set ColorCell = rng

For Each ColorCell In Rng
If ColorCell.Value > 1 Then      " You can define here"  "greater, smaller, equal  etc.."
ColorCell.Interior.Color = vbred

Else
ColorCell.Interior.ColorIndex = "vb(colour)or" xlNone
End If
Next

End Sub
```